# Custom names for MvvmCross converters

Tags: naming-conventions, converters, mvvmcross

Coming from a WPF background I am used to naming all value converters with the postfix word "Converter". I can do the same in MvvmCross however the usage style in the Android Axml is without the converter postfix.

Is it possible to still include the postfix word Converter without manually registering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MvvmCross registers the value converters using this filler - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Binders/MvxValueConverterRegistryFiller.cs#L20

```
        name = RemoveTail(name, "ValueConverter");
        name = RemoveTail(name, "Converter");
```

If you want to replace this registry filler, then you can:

- create a new filler class without the `RemoveTail` rules
- create a new `MyCustomBindingBuilder` which inherits from `MvxAndroidBindingBuilder`and override `protected virtual IMvxValueConverterRegistryFiller CreateValueConverterRegistryFiller()` in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/e6d10972b5c28e00e80acc3d9e8910961aa813d6/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/MvxCoreBindingBuilder.cs#L74 - this can return your custom filler
- you would return this custom binding builder in an overridden `protected virtual MvxAndroidBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()` in your `Setup` class for your app.

Comment: Amazing. MvvmCross allows you to override everything it seems.

Comment: Please also note that the `base` call adds `name = RemoveHead(name, "Mvx");` which you may or may not want - if you don't want it, then just don't call the `base` method.